# Android SimpleDateFormat.format giving wrong digit amount, like Minute "0040" randomly

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have an app for android that has a customized log format that I prefix with the Date for better searching.
Currently I'm using SimpleDateFormat but the results are inconsistent.

A few examples of this inconsistency, it is giving me:

```
2018/10/11 10:40:21.229 ____Verbose:
2018/0010/0011 0010:40:21.230 ____Verbose:
2018/10/11 10:40:21.232 ____Verbose:
...
2018/10/11 10:40:42.784 ____Verbose:
2018/10/11 010:040:042.786 ____Verbose:
2018/10/11 10:40:42.786 ____Verbose:
```

The code I'm using is:

```
private static final DateFormat LOGDATEFULL = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
private static String strErrorLevel(int errorLevel){
    if (errorLevel == VERBOSE  ) return " ____ VERBOSE: ";
    if (errorLevel == DEBUG    ) return " ____ DEBUG  : ";
    if (errorLevel == INFO     ) return " _.._ INFO   : ";
    if (errorLevel == WARN     ) return " _--_ WARN   : ";
    if (errorLevel == ERROR    ) return " _!!_ ERROR  : ";
    if (errorLevel == ANALYTICS) return " _++_ ANALYTC: ";
    return                              " _**_ ASSERT : ";
}
public static void customLog(String message, int level){
    Date currDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    Log.d(LOGDATEFULL.format(currDate) + " " + strErrorLevel(level) + message);
}
```

My system Locale is Portuguese Brazilian (pt-BR), and this occurs both when called from the main thread and calling from other threads.

Is there any other solution besides creating a function to manually make the string?

By the way, it occurs even in generating names for files like 'Output_2018-010-11.txt.

**Answer:** It was really what [Tom G](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52766100/10490162) and [lelloman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765850/10490162) pointed, in all the places that I used SimpleDateFormat, this one was the only that I had, which might be accessed by more than one thread at a time. I chose Tom G answer for the practicality of implementing in the existing code.

Thanks

Comment: What SimpleDateFormat are you using, the `java.text` or `android.icu.text` one? I've used that exact format with `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` many times and never saw this weird thing :\

Comment: Do you use multiple thread or something like an AsyncTask? If yes you may simple run into the problem that SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe.

Comment: Yes I used the java.text.SimpleDateFormat and the date from java.util.Date as the parameter.
Yes I have threads running, there's a bug in the Android Phone I'm using that if I don't call a startActivity for a new app on a separate thread it the OS simply won't call.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765850/272075) is to wrap the formatter in a `ThreadLocal` as so:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> LOGDATEFULL = new ThreadLocal<>() {
  @Override protected DateFormat initialValue() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
  }
}
```

Then you would access it by calling `.get().format()` instead.

This lets you avoid the synchronization overhead of coordinating access to a single instance, without worrying about creating separate copies for separate threads manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SimpleDateFormat` instance from multiple thread there is a chance that you have a race condition there, and as it's been pointed out, that class is not thread-safe. From [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create
>   separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access
>   a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

You should synchronize the access to that instance then:

```
public static void customLog(String message, int level){
    Date currDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    synchronized(LOGDATEFULL) {
        Log.d(LOGDATEFULL.format(currDate) + " " + strErrorLevel(level) + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: The alternative to synchronization is to wrap the formatter in a `ThreadLocal`.